# Where do I end up?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Given this streak of numbers:

```
1 2 11 4 101 6 111 8 1001 10 1011 12 1101 14 1111 16 ? ?
```

What will the last 2 numbers at the question marks be?

Hint:

> Positional notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Answer:

> It is most likely 17 in decimal or binary but you shift between each
>  until the end.
>
>
>  Binary + Decimal (missing 8 and 9?) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
>  ?? 17 or 00010001

Comment: Same comment as @lorimer. Plus: the question asks for 2 numbers following the sequence :)

Comment: 1. I posted first and 2. not the same answer so not "same comment"

Comment: I didn't know this was a competition :P. I was just commenting his answer first; no real intention behind that ;). Yours is the correct answer tho :)

Comment: Ok thanks, I also got the impression we where both wrong just now. Sorry about that.

Comment: how is this correct when it only gives a single number following the sequence?
(why this matters: if this is solved then I'd rather not waste effort trying to find the miniscule difference in mine)

Answer (score 1):

> 10001 20
>
> It's binary, but I wonder if you missed 8 and 9. If not, then the above should be right.

Comment: The ones you saying are missing aren't. Just as you noted the end-result, the pattern is correct. Your literal answer isn't correct tho. Look closer ;)